# Latex Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item for labeling environment

Tags: errors, lists, koma-script

```
\begin{labeling}
                    \item[ Frequency range: \SI{200}{\mega\hertz} to \SI{1000}  {\mega\hertz} in steps of \SI{1}{\mega\hertz}]
                  \item[ Stirrer positions: 36 ]
                  \item[ Cable length: \SI{1}{\metre}]
                  \item[ Termination resistors: \SI{50}{\ohm} at the beginning and end]             
\end{labeling}
```

What is wrong in my code? How to use the `labeling` environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where does `labeling`come from?  Can you please complete your code snippet to an compilable minimal working example we can play with? Important could be to know your used documentclass and other related packages to your problem ...

Comment: `labeling` takes the longest item description as mandatory argument.

Answer (score 6):

`labeling` is defined with all KOMA-classes and available with apackage `scrbase`. It takes a mandatory argument, the item with the longest width for alignment.

[image: pradeepLabeling]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{labeling}{Termination resistors:}
\item[Frequency range:] \SI{200}{\mega\hertz} to \SI{1000}  {\mega\hertz} in steps of \SI{1}{\mega\hertz} 
\item[Stirrer positions:] 36
\item[Cable length:] \SI{1}{\metre}
\item[Termination resistors:] \SI{50}{\ohm} at the beginning and end
\end{labeling}
\end{document}
```